# Circular Arrangement of students

Tags: probability

$6$ male students and $3$ female students sit around a round table. The probability that no $2$ female students sit beside each other can be expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

Comment: A product of coprime positive integers is $>1$, and hence cannot be a probability, UNLESS both integers are $1$, in which case the number you get by multiplying them is too big to be the probability of this event.

Comment: Please let me know if my edits are correct.

Comment: Are the students of the same gender distinguishable?

Comment: Of course they are.....

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked here. Is there a uniform probability distribution, making all seating arrangements equally likely, therefore all probabilities explicitly computable rationals (in particular this $\frac ab$), and is this just a weird question that requires that computation anyway as an intermediate step **or** is there an unknown probability distribution and are we just given the information that somehow this particular probability is rational? Guess it must be the first, since the second option does not seem to allow any answer. Saying "uniform distribution" is no luxury.

Answer (score 2):

One of the chairs is a throne, and the Queen, who is one of the women, sits there.

That leaves $8$ chairs, of which we must choose $2$ for the remaining women. There are $\dbinom{8}{2}$ equally likely ways to do this.

Now we count the *good* choices, where no two women are neighbours.The two chairs next to the Queen can't be used. So effectively we want to choose $2$ from the remaining $6$. But $5$ of these pairs consist of neighbouring chairs. So our probability is
$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}-5}{\binom{8}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

At first make the female students sit around the round table.This can be done in $(3-1)!=2$ different ways.

Now in between the female students there are $3$ places. You have to divide the $6$ male students into 3 groups. This can be done in this way: You first consider all the male students are same which implies that they can be divided into 3 groups in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. In each such selection we can get $6!$ different arrangements. So the total number of arrangements is $10 \cdot6!$

So the total no. of ways in which the students can be seated with no two female students side by side=$2\cdot10\cdot6!$.

And total no. ways in which the students can be seated is $(9-1)!$ ways.

So the probability is $\frac{2\cdot10\cdot6!}{8!}=\frac{2\cdot10}{7\cdot8}=\frac{5}{14}$

So $a+b=19$

Comment: Please use $\cdot$ for multiplication, which you get with \cdot.  Periods look too much like decimal points.  Sometimes you might like $\times$, which you get with \times.

Comment: @Lord_Farin:  I agree with the final answer.  Distinguishable or not doesn't make any difference in the ratio.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am very lazy......... so period is what I tend to use most of the times for multiplication...... From now on I will try to follow you...

Comment: @RossMillikan You are completely correct. I knew I should have delayed my response until the family brain cell was available again. AAK: Please edit your answer so that I can cancel my erroneous downvote. Apologies for that.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I dont find any mistake in my arguement ( so i dont have anything to correct , I guess)...

Comment: The problem was that my downvote was over an hour ago so I couldn't undo it. There is no problem with your argument (which is why it doesn't deserve my downvote and I wanted to cancel it). I've edited it now; downvote cancelled.

Comment: Ok...... I didn't understand you..... @Lord_Farin.

Comment: Hey friends ,probability and counting is never clear to me.I am not able to solve twisted problems.What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Seat the first woman first-she can go anywhere.  The next one can go in a seat with one blank, probability $\frac 28$ or in a seat at least two away, probability $\frac 48$.  If the second is one away, the last one has four seats that are not next to one of the others out of seven.  If the second is at least two away, the third has three choices out of seven.  So the total chance is $\frac 14 \cdot \frac 47 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 37=\frac 5{14}$